# 48AMP kiln on 60 AMP breaker *must be* direct wired in Canada?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, code-compliance, kiln

I am trying to find out what part of the Canadian electrical code requires that the 48AMP kiln, on a 60AMP breaker requires that it must be direct wired, instead of using the NEMA 6-50 receptacle permitted in USA. I would like my kiln to be mobile, and wonder if there is a work around of some kind.

Comment: I'm not sure that is permitted in USA.

Comment: 48 Amp continuous upsize +25% to 60 Amp rated breaker/wire/receptacle/etc. So a 6-50 wouldn't work anywhere. There are (in a quick search) NEMA 14-60, but not as far as I can tell any 6-60. But whether 14-60 (i.e., also neutral) would (a) work for you or (b) be allowed by code - I have no idea.

Comment: @Harper - the manufacturer's website shows the kiln being delivered with a 6-50, recommended breaker 60AMP but has indicated in Canada code does not allow it.

Comment: They do sell a NEMA 14-60 receptacle, FWIW...

Comment: If the kiln is sometimes sold with a 6-50, then it's probably not 48A continuous.  More likely it draws 48A for some number of minutes to get up to temperature, and then switches the element on and off as needed, likely with something like a 20-40% duty cycle, to maintain temperature just like an oven does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never found the answer to the specific question "what part of the code", but I did speak with some electricians who indicated that if the kiln were permanently installed it would be considered a 'continuous load', similar to a 'heating appliance' like a stove or a furnace.

However, my kiln is on wheels which I use to roll it into the corner when not in use. As such, the electrician said it is a temporary appliance that *should not* be direct wired. As such he installed a 60 amp breaker and the correct receptacle for the plug on the kiln (6-50), and a switch inline between the two. He indicated it is safer to turn the plug off first and then remove the plug instead of pulling the plug with 240V at 50 amps available.

Comment: I'd just switch the breaker off, rather than adding a switch in-line...

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer this!

Comment: @Ecnerwal The duty cycle on the switch is in the tens of thousands. The duty cycle on a breaker is in much lower. It is also expensive compared to the switch.